# yii2 AR find via 2 relative tables

Tags: yii2, relation

I have 5 tables:
master, 
region, 
service,
master_service,
master_region.

In model of Master add getters:

```
public function getServices(){
    return $this->hasMany(Service::className(), ['id' => 'service_id'])
    ->viaTable(MasterService::tableName(), ['master_id' => 'id']);
}
public function getRegions(){
    return $this->hasMany(Region::className(), ['id' => 'region_id'])
    ->viaTable(MasterRegion::tableName(), ['master_id' => 'id']);
}
```

All is working! But I can't implement the search condition, for example, to select all masters, when the service.id = 1, region.id=1.
Please help how to do it "nicely" means yii2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Master `getServices` should by

```
public function getServices(){
    return $this->hasMany(Service::className(), ['id' => 'service_id']);
}
```

then `$master->getServices()` returns ActiveQuery and you can use it for more advanced [query](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-db-query-builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
Master::find()->innerJoinWith([
'services' => function ($query) use ($serviceId) {
        $query->where(['service.id' => $id]);
    },
'regions' => function ($query) use ($regionId) {
        $query->where(['region.id' => $regionId]);
    }
])->all();
```

See documentation https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md#joining-with-relations-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I tried

```
$model   = Master::find()->joinWith(['services', 'regions'])->where(['service.id'=>$service_id, 'region.id'=>$region_id])->all();
```

And its works!

Comment: this works, but you can do it with 2 less joins. You are joining 4 tables right now and you only need to be joining 2. if you need speed and you are working with a lot of records you can improve this. MasterService already has service_id and you do not need to get to Service.id when you can compare it with MasterService.service_id